# I have a PHP error logging every second and I don't know

Tags: php

I am receiving the following PHP error on my error log and I don't know what it is for.

It logs the following info

```
Date -  Level    - Originating
IP Address   - Error Message     - Apache
Error Code -    File
Path

2022-08-17 21:07:46 Error   (my ip adress)  Got error 'Passing INI directive through FastCGI: unable to set 'secure_php''   AH01071
```

An error has been logged for every second of that minute in my error log.

Can anyone help me to understand what this is and give guidance/article/video on how I can fix it please.  Will highly appreciate it

Comment: Check what your ini has it in. Sounds like something in there that you dont have on the server.

Comment: If you have a linux server or Mac, you can try `grep -R secure_php .` from your document root to see if it's referenced anywhere in your files.